# Deducing F-distribution PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $V\sim \chi^2(n)$ and $W\sim \chi^2(m)$ indep. r.v.

I want to find the PDF for $X=\frac{V/n}{W/m}$.

For that I define $h(v,w)=(v,v/n\cdot m/w)=(v,x)$.
So, $h^{-1}(v,x)=(v,\frac{v \cdot m}{x\cdot n})$

We know that $f_{V,X}=f_{V,W}(h^{-1}(v,x))\cdot |det(Dh^{-1}(v,x))|$.

Because they are independent, $f_{V,W}=f_{V}\cdot f_{W}$, so doing the math I get,
$\displaystyle f_{V,X}=\frac{v^{(n+m)/2-1}e^{-\frac{v}{2}(1+m/(x\cdot n))}}{2^{(m+n)/2} \cdot \Gamma(n/2)\cdot \Gamma(m/2)}\cdot \frac{m}{x^2 n} \cdot \left(\frac{m}{xn}\right)^{m/2-1}$.

Now integrating with respect to $v$, we get $\displaystyle f_{X}=\frac{\Gamma((n+m)/2)}{ \Gamma(n/2)\cdot \Gamma(m/2)}\cdot \frac{1}{x} \cdot \left(\frac{m}{xn}\right)^{(m/2)}\cdot \left(1+\frac{m}{xn}\right)^{-(m+n)/2}$.

According to the book I'm using, I should have got instead:
$\displaystyle f_{X}=\frac{\Gamma((n+m)/2)}{ \Gamma(n/2)\cdot \Gamma(m/2)}\cdot x^{(n-2)/2} \cdot \left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^{(m/2)}\cdot \left(1+\frac{nx}{m}\right)^{-(m+n)/2}$.

So, my question is where did I go wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computation is 100% correct. The answer provided by your book is wrong.  You can see this by integrating the book's density over $x \in [0,\infty)$:  it will give $(n/m)^{(m-n)/2} \ne 1$ if $m \ne n$.  Feel free to refer to the [Wikipedia page for the $F$-ratio distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-Ratio_Distribution).

Comment: Hi @heropup, thanks for you answer.  Are you sure that the 1st pdf is right? I followed your advice, and I went to the wikipedia page, and I saw the book's density on that page as the right one...

Comment: I am **absolutely** certain.  There is no possibility of mistake; your answer is correct, the book's answer is wrong, and Wikipedia's formula is **also correct**.

Comment: The book's answer is erroneous because the correct factor should be $(n/m)^{\color{red} n/2}$, not $m/2$ in the exponent.  Once this change is made, the densities are algebraically equivalent.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I've just integrated like you said, you're completely right. Could you please tell me then why do I have an apparently different pdf from the wikipedia? I thought that the pdf would be indifferent to different h transformations, as long as they were bijective...

Comment: You simply need to perform the necessary algebraic transformations to obtain the form shown in the Wikipedia article.  The reason for the way it is written is that it is more convenient to remember, since $d_1/d_2$ is the ratio of the numerator d.f. to the denominator d.f.

Comment: Got it. Many thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. I can deduce like this:

When V and U are two $\chi^2$ independent random variables:   $f_V(v)=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{m}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}v^{(\frac{m}{2})-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}v}$
$f_U(u)=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}u^{(\frac{n}{2})-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u}$
with $m$ and $n$ degrees of freedom, then, the pdf for $W=V/U$ is:
$$\begin{align}
f_{V/U}(\omega)&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}|u|f_U(u)f_V(u\omega)du\\
&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}u\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}u^{\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u}  \frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{m}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}(u\omega)^{\frac{m}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u\omega}du\\
&=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{m}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}  \omega^{\frac{m}{2}-1} \int_{0}^{+\infty}u^{\frac{n}{2}}u^{\frac{m}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}u(1+\omega)}du\\
&=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{m}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}  \omega^{\frac{m}{2}-1} \int_{0}^{+\infty}u^{\frac{n+m}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}u(1+\omega)}du\\
&=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{m}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}  \omega^{\frac{m}{2}-1} (\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2})}{(\frac{1}{2}(1+\omega))^{\frac{n+m}{2}}})\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}\frac{\omega^{\frac{m}{2}-1}}{(1+\omega)^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}
\end{align}$$

Then, the pdf for $W=\frac{V/m}{U/n}$ is:
$$\begin{align}
f_{\frac{V/m}{U/n}}&=f_{\frac{n}{m}V/U}\\
&=\frac{m}{n}f_{V/U}(\frac{m}{n}\omega)\\
&=\frac{m}{n}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}\frac{(\frac{m}{n}\omega)^{\frac{m}{2}-1}}{(1+\frac{m}{n}\omega)^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}\frac{m}{n}\frac{(\frac{m}{n}\omega)^{\frac{m}{2}-1}}{(n+m\omega)^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}n^{\frac{n+m}{2}}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})}\frac{m^{\frac{m}{2}}n^{\frac{n}{2}}\omega^{\frac{m}{2}-1}}{(n+m\omega)^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}
\end{align}$$